# Integrating CRM 2011 and SharePoint 2010 using ADFS 2.0

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint, adfs, single-sign-on, microsoft-dynamics-crm

As the title quite accurately reflects above, I have the following environment that I'm looking to tie all together:

1. CRM 2011 IFD (already using ADFS 2.0 successfully)
2. SharePoint 2010

There is integration between the two products in the form of document storage. SharePoint basically becomes the repository for documents that are attached to particular entities in CRM. Awesome stuff.

Now, as of this moment, I have the two products working, and I have the integration working successfully. The one thing I can't seem to get around is a login page when first accessing the Documents area inside CRM (it is a request for SharePoint data). After logging in, I am able to navigate the Document storage without issue.

What I'm looking to accomplish is to have my auth token that is issued when I sign into CRM work to validate me against SharePoint.

Simpler terms, I don't want to see another login screen.

Any clues? I can provide more details about the environment as needed, but things are basically pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your documents are specific to each entity? For each new instance of our custom entity, SharePoint makes the user manually specify a "location", which must be an existing SharePoint Folder.

Worse than that, our CRM users can only access an entity that has been shared with them by the entity owner; whereas, everyone can access that instance's documents unless I manually set up the security for each SharePoint folder to match the list of user's with whom that entity has been shared.

Comment: No, this more about ADFS claims-auth between two products instead of authorization of users in regards to the documents itself. I actually have an answer to this, I just have yet to write it.